# Ubuntu 14.04 - Slow boot (link is slow to respond and SRST failed errno=-16)

Tags: 14.04, boot, ssd

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on a 20gb SSD installed on a mSATA to SATA adapter. During boot a lot of unpleasant delays occur. I've probably found one of the critical steps in dmesg output:

```
[    2.966380] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    2.968766] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[    7.176076] ata4: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   11.712060] ata4: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   12.180092] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   12.188778] ata4.00: ATA-8: SATA SSD, S5FAM018, max UDMA/100
[   12.188780] ata4.00: 39091248 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[   12.204724] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/100s
```

ATA4 is the SSD. Windows boot on the same drive is OK. 
Does anyone can help me, please?

Many thanks in advance.
Marco

Comment: have you checked hdd cable and connectors? it could be a connection related problem..

Comment: yes, that's not the problem. The problem doesn't occur during windows boot..
Anyway thanks for the support! I would have expected more help from this community..